# Cannot reboot to Ubuntu from Microsoft

Tags: reboot

Been using for years.  New Dell laptop and I left the MS OS on the computer and loaded Ubuntu 16.04.2.  I then switched at boot to Microsoft, and now the computer will not reboot back to Ubuntu.  How do I get back to my Ubuntu OS!?!?

Comment: You have to give us more information. Do you see the GRUB menu? Are you able to see Windows and Ubuntu in that menu? If you select Ubuntu, exactly what happens next, and what do you see? Are there any error messages?

Comment: By "Microsoft", you mean Windows, right?

Answer (score -1):

windows likes to put itself at the top of the boot order. a work arond is this:

boot from a live CD. install efibootmgr.

find the file /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi. copy it to /efi/boot/bootx64.efi. if the file is there already overwrite it. this makes grub the default loader.

next use efibootmgr to delete all entries in the boot list. restart you computer, be sure ubuntu is the fiirst OS you boot into so it is placed in the first slot.

Comment: I tried booting from a live CD, but it still would not boot

Comment: secure boot has to be off, and cd has to have priority boot.

Comment: How do I make the CD the priority boot, I did it once before, but forgot how...

Comment: in the system setting to make it permanent. or holding a function key at boot to get a boot menu. the right key varies from computer to computer. t F2, F10, F12  are most common

Comment: Before starting to copy files, and overwriting existing files, and installing additional software, why don't you find out more information from the user about exactly how/where their boot is failing. At least make backups of files before overwriting. Maybe recommending boot-repair might be more user friendly and safer?

Answer (score -1):

Windows likes to take over the booting whenever possible, and doesn't recognize Linux partitions.

You'll need to boot from a live CD or live USB and reinstall GRUB.  This will make GRUB the default boot loader again, and should recognize both Ubuntu and MS Partitions.

Comment: How do you know that GRUB is the problem? You haven't asked the user any questions yet. Why not recommend boot-repair?

Comment: @andy -- when he boots into windows he will have the same problem unless he does my fix